# C# Firewall rule doesn't work with my .exe file

Tags: c#, .net, api, exe, rules

I have a self hosted web api C# application. So to get access from other device (phone for example) to api I need to create a firewall rule. I created a firewall rule for concrete port and application (builded C# exe file). Then I try to get access for api with ip:port/ and it doesn't work. If i dont specify application while creating firewall rule then rule works good. What is the problem?

Comment: What configuring has to do with programming (especially with C#)? Do you create rule programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i create rule programmatically, but i tried create rule directly in Firewall - same result

Comment: Sounds like you have a working code. Nothing to do on this site then. Check out [server fault](https://serverfault.com/) if you suspect the rule itself has the problem.